# string_count and regex in R

Tags: r, regex, stringi

I want to use str_count from the stringi package to count special symbols in a string.

Something like this:

```
library(stringi)
data$var1 <- stri_count(data$var, pattern="[[:punct:]]")
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
Error in stri_count(data$var, pattern = "[[:punct:]]") : 
  you have to specify either `regex`, `fixed`, `coll`, or `charclass`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `stri_count(data$var, regex="[[:punct:]]")` or `stri_count_regex(data$var, pattern="[[:punct:]]")`

Comment: @mt1022 thanks. the stringi documentation was a bit vague in respect of inputs.

Comment: There is even an example of usage [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.1.5/topics/stri_count). And I even found an SO post related to its usage. Closed as a dupe.